# Method POST Error (405) using WSAPI in Orbit (Kepler project/Lua)

Tags: post, lua, http-status-code-405, orbit

trying write a web application using Lua's MVC framework called Orbit.  I have a local server (WSAPI) up and running my application but every time I submit a post request I get a 405 error.  I think that this is probably a configuration issue, but then again, i'm not really sure.  How do you change the WSAPI configuration to allow POSTs? If this isn't the error, what is?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an error in your configuration. Orbit should be writing log files somewhere. Those should give you more info.